# Remove shortcode after changing theme

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have just invested in a new wordpress theme for my site and I have a problem: my old theme proposed a shortcode "dropcap". When I activate my new theme, the letter encapsulated by the shortcode disappears ... Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where is the shortcode implemented?  Is there anything in your error log?

Comment: Hi @GentlemanMax, the shortcode is directly implemented in content editor  like this[dropcap size=small]N[/dropcap]. No error in my log.

Comment: I mean the code that makes the shortcode work.  E.g. is it in a plugin, was it part of your old theme, etc?

Comment: // Dropcap Shortcode
if ( ! function_exists( 'cb_dropcap_shortcode' ) ) {
  function cb_dropcap_shortcode( $atts, $content = NULL ) {
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'size' => 'small',
    'text' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

  return '<span class="drop-sm">' .  $content  . '</span>';
 }
 add_shortcode('dropcap', 'cb_dropcap_shortcode');
}

Comment: Did you add that shortcode function to your new themes functions.php file?  Also, you can enable debug by setting the debug to true in wp-config.php - that might help you find any errors if there are any.  PM me a link to your site.